# Can't position child of RelativeLayout View without changing its size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

If I try to set the top/left margins of the child of a RelativeLayout view so that the child view would appear partially off the right/bottom of the screen, the problem is that the view is shrunk in size and appears fully on the screen (which satisfies the top/left margins, but changes the size). I don't want the size to change.

I programmatically set the position of a child view of a RelativeLayout view by setting the top and left margins, something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams childViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(250,250);
childView = new ImageView(this);    
relLayoutView.addView(childView);
childViewParams.leftMargin = somethingBigEnoughToPutOffRightHandSide;
childViewParams.topMargin = something;
childView.setLayoutParams(childViewParams);
```

If I set the top/left margins such that this child view should appear partly off left/top part of the screen, everything works as expected, no change in size, and the view moves partially off screen.

**How can I specify the position of the view so that the size of the view is never changed, no matter the position, partially or fully off screen?**

Answer (score 1):

All that is needed is to also set the right and bottom margins to negative values exceeding the possible size of the view and the screen.  Something like this:

```
RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.MarginLayoutParams) someView.getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(leftMargin,rightMargin,-1000,-1000);
someView.setLayoutParams(params);
```